# How does regex query work on lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to implement luecene search engine in my application.

I am using lucene 5.4.1

I have successfully implemented wildequeries and normal queries of lucene.

But my main focus is to search specific text in a text file with regex patterns.

Index Writer code:

```
public IndexWriter generateIndex(String docsPath) throws IOException {

      String indexPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") +File.separator+"indexDirectory";
        if (indexPath == null) {
          throw new IOException("System property 'java.io.tmpdir' does not specify a tmp dir");
        }
        File tmpDir = new File(indexPath);
        if (!tmpDir.exists()) {
          boolean created = tmpDir.mkdirs();
          if (!created) {
            throw new IOException("Unable to create tmp dir " + tmpDir);
          }
        }

    boolean create = true;
    final Path docDir = Paths.get(docsPath);
    if (!Files.isReadable(docDir)) {
        System.out.println("Document directory '" + docDir.toAbsolutePath()
                + "' does not exist or is not readable, please check the path");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Date start = new Date();
    try {
        System.out.println("Indexing to directory '" + indexPath + "'...");

        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexPath));
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

        if (create) {
            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
        } else {
            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
        }

        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
        indexDocs(writer, docDir);
        setIndexWriter(writer);

        Date end = new Date();
        System.out.println(end.getTime() - start.getTime() + " total milliseconds");
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(" caught a " + e.getClass() + "\n with message: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return getIndexWriter();
}

static void indexDocs(final IndexWriter writer, Path path) throws IOException {
    if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                try {
                    indexDoc(writer, file, attrs.lastModifiedTime().toMillis());
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                    // don't index files that can't be read.
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    } else {
        indexDoc(writer, path, Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toMillis());
    }
}

static void indexDoc(IndexWriter writer, Path file, long lastModified) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(file)) {
        Document doc = new Document();
        Field pathField = new StringField("path", file.toString(), Field.Store.NO);
        doc.add(pathField);

        doc.add(new LongField("modified", lastModified, Field.Store.NO));
        doc.add(new TextField("contents",
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));

        if (writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE) {
            System.out.println("adding " + file);
            writer.addDocument(doc);
        } else {
            System.out.println("updating " + file);
            writer.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.toString()), doc);
        }
    }
}
```

Index Searching Code:

```
public IndexReader searchExecutor(String index, String queryString, RegexCapabilities capability) throws Exception {

    String field = "contents";
    String queries = null;
    boolean raw = false;
    int hitsPerPage = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(index)));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

    BufferedReader in = null;
    Query q = new RegexpQuery(new Term("text", queryString));
    q = q.rewrite(reader);

    RegexQuery query = new RegexQuery(new Term("\\s*(FIND|find)"));

     if (capability != null)
          query.setRegexImplementation(capability);

    System.out.println("Searching for: " + query.toString(field));
    searcher.search(query, null, 1000);
    doSearch(in, searcher, query, hitsPerPage, raw, queries == null && queryString == null);
    //reader.close();
    return reader;

}

public static void doSearch(BufferedReader in, IndexSearcher searcher, Query query, int hitsPerPage, boolean raw,
        boolean interactive)
                throws IOException {

    TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 5 * hitsPerPage);
    ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
    //generateIndex.deleteDocuments(query);
    //generateIndex.getDirectory();
    // TermsEnum.totalTermFreq();
    int numTotalHits = results.totalHits;
    System.out.println(numTotalHits + " total matching documents");
    int start = 0;
    int end = Math.min(numTotalHits, hitsPerPage);

    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        Document doc = searcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
        String path = doc.get("path");
        File file = new File(path);
        if (path != null) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + path);
            String title = doc.get("title");
            if (title != null) {
                System.out.println("   Title: " + doc.get("title"));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + "No path for this document");
        }

    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: The focus of lucene is to tokenize the text that is handed in appropriately so that no use of regular expressions is required. So how is the content of your text files structured (separated by whitespaces...?), how do you want to be able to search for it?

Comment: In short, I think you approach is flawed ...

Comment: @cheffe lucene supports regex query and has a packaage named regex query.

Comment: content of text file structure is seperated by whitespaces and i need to use regex to identify a pattern. For ex: i will use pattern to identify variables defined in a java file

Comment: I know that regexp is included. But you will not get good performance out of this :) It will work, but this is not the way it is intended to work. Patterns can be done with `PhraseQuery` or `SpanQuery`. But going for Patterns you are going to neglect the performance of the index.

Comment: its ok with me, can you please share any regexpquery example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about search with regular expressions in lucene.

1. You are using `RegexQuery` which is deprecated so try `RegexpQuery`
2. Your regEx-example starts with `\s*` but you do not use [KeywordTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/KeywordTokenizer.html). Most other tokenizer will remove (aka "split at") whitespace
3. Your regEx-example is not purely lower case. But standard analyzer contains LowerCaseFilter. Be aware: your regEx will go directly against the tokens of your index (not against the original text)

--> read [Supported RegExp syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html) and [syntax in ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax) and [TestRegexpRandom (test class)](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/25296006/) and play with https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke on your index.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. I am trying to implement regexpquery, but not able to run it, can you please share any running piece of code, where regexpquery are working?

Comment: I added reference to test class